# Write the math expression in C ++

Tags: c++, math

There was a problem with the mathematical expression written below:

[image: mathematical expression]

```
cin >> value;

dividend = tan(fabs(2*value*value + 5 * value - 31.15)) 
    + log(fabs(value*value - 2.5)) / log(5.0);

divider = pow(fabs(pow(sin(value*value*value), 2)
    + fabs(0.33*(log(fabs(value*value - 2.5) / log(5.0))))), 1 / 5.0); 

result = dividend / divider;
```

Result is an invalid value. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by an "invalid value"?

Comment: It has to do with PEMDAS.

Comment: Break it down into more statements so you can more easily see what's happening, set a breakpoint at the start and then step through it with a debugger.  You've made it hard to read, which is why you can't spot the problem.

Comment: Also there is a x in the second line. 
2*value*value + 5 * x - 31.15

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth incorrect calculation of the formula.

Comment: @user38034 is not the problem. Forgot to rename the variable in the example.

Comment: log(5.0) inside the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have balanced parentheses for the denominator, or `divider` if you wish, they are not correctly placed.  As Yves Daoust observed, you misplaced the division by `log(5.0)`.

Spacing out the subexpression and parenthesization on different lines should help you see this:

```
pow(
    fabs(
          pow(sin(value*value*value), 2)
           + fabs(
                  0.33 * ( 
                            log( fabs(value*value - 2.5) / log(5.0) )
                         )
                 )
        )
, 1 / 5.0);
```

Also, why represent one-third by 0.33, unless you are really casual about precision?  A division by 3 would be portable...